# Excel Using Cell Reference as a Logical Operator with Multiple Criteria and Looking Up a Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logical-operators

Not really sure how to tackle this one. Looking to populate the highlighted cells (F15, F16, G15, G16) with the correct CMG code based on 2 rules. The rules are found in the upper table in columns D:H. Each rule is split into 3 columns, the metric specified, the operator and the value. Most rules check motor score, while some check age and in some cases there is only 1 rule. After the CMG is filled in cells F15 and F16 I will need to then use that code to lookup the weight in columns I:L (which should be a fairly simple task).

Would prefer to accomplish this with a formula instead of VBA. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

**Note, the highlighted cells should be the following values:**

- F15 = 202
- F16 = 105
- G15 = 1.2534
- G16 = 1.9391

This question is very similar to this one, but I have 2 sets of rules/criteria. Also my rules are able to switch between Motor, Age and (blank). 
[excel using cell reference as a logical operator and looking up a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034984/excel-using-cell-reference-as-a-logical-operator-and-looking-up-a-value)

Comment: You could also use the operators directly in a Countifs e.g. =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B15,A$2:A$10,C15,D$2:D$10&E$2:E$10,C15,G$2:G$10&H$2:H$10)*B$2:B$10) would work for Bob, but would need refinement to work in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula to get the desired row in your table for "Bob", which you can then fill down for "Steve", etc. (you can then use this result in an `INDEX` formula to get CMG and Weight). Note that you have to commit it as an array formula (`ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`).

```
=MATCH("TRUETRUETRUE",($A$2:$A$12=B15)&IF(LEN($C$2:$C$12)>0,CHOOSE(MATCH($C$2:$C$12,$C$14:$D$14,0),CHOOSE(MATCH($D$2:$D$12,{">",">=","<","<="},0),$C15>$E$2:$E$12,$C15>=$E$2:$E$12,$C15<$E$2:$E$12,$C15<=$E$2:$E$12),CHOOSE(MATCH($D$2:$D$12,{">",">=","<","<="},0),$D15>$E$2:$E$12,$D15>=$E$2:$E$12,$D15<$E$2:$E$12,$D15<=$E$2:$E$12)),TRUE)&IF(LEN($F$2:$F$12)>0,CHOOSE(MATCH($F$2:$F$12,$C$14:$D$14,0),CHOOSE(MATCH($G$2:$G$12,{">",">=","<","<="},0),$C15>$H$2:$H$12,$C15>=$H$2:$H$12,$C15<$H$2:$H$12,$C15<=$H$2:$H$12),CHOOSE(MATCH($G$2:$G$12,{">",">=","<","<="},0),$D15>$H$2:$H$12,$D15>=$H$2:$H$12,$D15<$H$2:$H$12,$D15<=$H$2:$H$12)),TRUE),0)
```

**EDIT** Tom Sharp has a good suggestion to use COUNTIFS, which will allow you to use the logical operators directly. This results in a shorter, more straightforward formula (you still have to commit it as an array formula):

```
=MATCH(4,IF($C$2:$C$12=$C$14,COUNTIFS(B15,A$2:A$12,C15,D$2:D$12&E$2:E$12)>0,1)+IF($F$2:$F$12=$C$14,COUNTIFS(B15,A$2:A$12,C15,G$2:G$12&H$2:H$12)>0,1)+IF($C$2:$C$12=$D$14,COUNTIFS(B15,A$2:A$12,D15,D$2:D$12&E$2:E$12)>0,1)+IF($F$2:$F$12=$D$14,COUNTIFS(B15,A$2:A$12,D15,G$2:G$12&H$2:H$12)>0,1),0)
```

Basically, for each row, you're checking each of the rules for both Motor and Age to make sure all four cases are either true or don't apply.

Comment: Wow that is great!!  Can you explain or link to a resource that elaborates on what is being done?  Really really appreciate that!